# Does adding jars to lib/ext have any limitation?

Tags: java, jar

I tried adding the following jars to `$java/jre/lib/ext` and `$java/jdk/jre/lib/ext`:

- commons-csv-1.2.jar
- junit.jar
- hamcrest-cor.jar

If I import class/library from any jar and tried to compile using the command `javac ClassName.java`, it always returns package [path|name] doesn't exist.

I don't know what causes this issue, any idea?

Comment: This must  be done from the root of the source tree. Are you compiling from root path or not?

Comment: do you mean classpath?

Comment: Yeah you are running from correct path ?For ex: you have to specify the path till class in jar file

Comment: You can include your jar files in the "javac" command using the "-cp" option.

javac -cp ".;/home/path/mail.jar;/home/path/servlet.jar;" MyJavaFile.java.
Instead of "-cp" you could also use "-classpath" as 

javac -classpath ".;/home/path/mail.jar;/home/path/servlet.jar;" MyJavaFile.java

Comment: You should almost never install additional files into the JVM distribution. Use a dependency manager such as Maven or Gradle instead.

Comment: You should not use `lib/ext` as it will affect all applications running on that Java version. This could lead to incorrect behavior of those applications if it depends on classes in those jars and you provide the wrong version. In any case, `lib/ext` is considered deprecated and will be removed in a future version.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel do you mean i have to copy and past all jars i added in lib/ext to every jdk version ?

Comment: @chrylis plz illustrate, why?

Comment: @Khwarizm No, those jars should be part of your application, and the application should declare its classpath, and as chrylis says: use Maven or Gradle for dependency management and compilation.

Answer (score 1):

The Java compiler generates the Java bytecode (the `.class` files) from your Java source (`.java`) files. As it is compiling a class, e.g. `ClassName.java`, if that class `import`s any other class like e.g. `import pkg.SomeClass`, it does something like like this (details [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html)):

1. either compile that class from source (e.g. `pkg/SomeClass.java`), or
2. expect the bytecode of that class (e.g. `pkg/SomeClass.class) to be available on the`classpath` (in a folder, or a jar).

Since you depend on the class from certain other jars, you'd want `javac` to take the second route above. A rather simple way to do this is specify the jar files (where you know that the imported classes exist) on the `classpath` using `javac -cp <path/to/jar>` or `javac -classpath <path/to/jar>`.

The [JRE extension mechanism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/install.html) is something related to extending the Java Runtime Environment. Although `javac` might consult the extensions directory on a JRE installation, it seems that it is better to keep away from it.